# wpf chart contol

Tags: wpf-controls

I am looking for a chart control that incluse a scroll bar and can perform data virtualization.
Thank you,
Tali.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Toolkit is available for free [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/29117)
There are also the .NET 4 chart controls [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)